# How to get values in PowerBI between two dates in two different columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi i have an issue i cant fix in PowerBI i dont understand DAX that mutch.
I have a half solution in DAX and an example what i have tryed.
I have the solution in SQL.

**WANTED RESULT**

I need to get the "time" result summed up
that have values between the two selected values.
IMPORTANT if one rows of values starts **before AND after** the selected values then the operation was active that time and shall be included.

[image]

@sdate = '2020'

@sdate = '2021'

```
Select *
From @temp
where (datepart(year,startdate) <= @sdate and datepart(year,enddate))
or (startdate between @sdate and @edate)
or (enddate between @sdate and @edate)
```

If i do it in SSMS i get the right rows

---

But in PowerBI i have some issue

I need to be able to choose två year

- Year from startdate
- Year from enddate

This part work but not the full solution
I just get row 3 and 4 as it sould of this solution.

---

***UPDATED
NOW I DONT EVEN GET THIS PART RIGHT***
[image]
[image]

---

I want all the green to include and exclude the red

```
Antal (under året) =
var SelectedYearStart = CONVERT(SELECTEDVALUE(TEST[startdate].[Year]), INTEGER)
var SelectedYearEnd = CONVERT(SELECTEDVALUE(TEST[enddate].[Year]), INTEGER)
return CALCULATE(SUM(TEST[time]),ALLCROSSFILTERED(TEST),year(TEST[startdate])<=SelectedYearStart , year(TEST[enddate])>=SelectedYearEnd)
```

My guess was this

```
Antal (under året) =
var SelectedYearStart = CONVERT(SELECTEDVALUE(TEST[startdate].[Year]), INTEGER)
var SelectedYearEnd = CONVERT(SELECTEDVALUE(TEST[enddate].[Year]), INTEGER)
return CALCULATE(SUM(TEST[time]),ALLCROSSFILTERED(TEST),year(TEST[startdate])<=SelectedYearStart , year(TEST[enddate])>=SelectedYearEnd || DATESBETWEEN(TEST[startdate],SelectedYearStart,SelectedYearEnd || DATESBETWEEN(TEST[enddate],SelectedYearStart,SelectedYearEnd)))
```

But then i get this error

[image]

TEST DATA

```
declare @sdate nvarchar(4)
declare @edate nvarchar(4)
set @sdate = '2020'
set @edate = '2021'
select @sdate sdate
select @edate edate
DEclare @temp table (time decimal(18,2) , startdate date, enddate date)
INSERT INTO  @temp
SELECT 5.0,'2019-01-01','2020-12-01' union all -- 
SELECT 5.0,'2021-01-01','2022-12-01' union all -- 
select 5.0,'2020-01-01','2021-12-01' union all        
select 5.0,'2019-01-01','2022-12-01' union all --
select 5.0,'2019-01-01','2019-12-01' union all --
select 5.0,'2022-01-01','2022-12-01' union all
select 5.0,'2020-01-01','2020-12-01' union all
select 5.0,'2021-01-01','2021-12-01'
--select 5.0,'2020-01-01','3000-01-01' --EXTRA
SELECT *
into TEST
FROM @temp
--ORDER BY startdate,enddate
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
var SelectedYearStart = SELECTEDVALUE(TEST[startdate].[Year])
var SelectedYearEnd = SELECTEDVALUE(TEST[enddate].[Year])
return CALCULATE(SUM(TEST[time]),
        ALL ( TEST[startdate].[Year]),
        ALL ( TEST[enddate].[Year]),
        KEEPFILTERS(
               (Year(TEST[startdate]) <= SelectedYearStart && 
                Year(TEST[enddate]) >= SelectedYearEnd)
            || (Year(TEST[startdate]) >= SelectedYearStart && 
                Year(TEST[startdate]) <= SelectedYearEnd) 
            || (Year(TEST[enddate]) >= SelectedYearStart && 
                Year(TEST[enddate]) <= SelectedYearEnd))
        )
```

First you need to clear the filters on the table that are created via the two slicers (`startdate.Year` and `enddate.Year`)

Then you need to pass in your complex filter query. Note that I'm using the `Year(..)` function because you can't reference columns from different tables in the filter section of the `Calculate` (and startdate.year and enddate.year are coming from two separate date tables created automatically by powerbi).

Finally you need to wrap that into a `KEEPFILTERS` statement to ensure that only the current row context is being applied to the expression.

Comment: It seams to be the right solution.
Im so gratefull for you help! =D, I tryed to count the rows also with the COUNTAX but it dint work. I need to spend some time to understand the Dax ALL insted of the ALLCROSSFILTERED and keepfilters.... With your solution  and if i can understand how to count the rows in this solution i can devide the sum / rowcount

Comment: I found that @Joao Leal dint have the answer... Like values before selectedstart and trow selected start but not pass selected end was missing (PS the enddate from row 1 sould be 2020 as the image show) i think that row 2 also is missing

Comment: Sorry when i runned it one by one only one of the rows was accepted, accept the 2019.2019 and 2022.2022 but after this code i dont know if its ment to miss. The only row thats was good is row 3

Comment: I don't understand what is not working. See a demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/i23bka4mh8kyf55/demo.pbix?dl=0